# Get list of days from selected month

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate

I want to get list of days in selected month.
For example, If user select feb then it show 1 to 28 0r 29 days. How can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: where and how do you want to show

Comment: that is automatically done by `UIDatePicker`.

Comment: @Retro I want to pass list of days to show value at all days when user select month only.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/jaykz52/CKCalendar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code, I have given the today's date to find the list of dates in this month. You can give some other date to find the list of that given month.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSMutableArray *datesThisMonth = [NSMutableArray array];
NSRange rangeOfDaysThisMonth = [cal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit forDate:today];

NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSEraCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];
[components setHour:0];
[components setMinute:0];
[components setSecond:0];

for (NSInteger i = rangeOfDaysThisMonth.location; i < NSMaxRange(rangeOfDaysThisMonth); ++i) {
    [components setDay:i];
    NSDate *dayInMonth = [cal dateFromComponents:components];
    [datesThisMonth addObject:dayInMonth];
}
NSLog(@"datesThisMonth: %@", datesThisMonth);
```

Comment: Perfect. I thought I remembered there being a way to do this, but couldn't find the rangeOfUnit:inUnit:forDate: method. I was in the process of outlining the steps to do this manually when I saw posts using that method. NSCalendar is an incredibly rich class!

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the number of days in specified month

```
NSCalendar* cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

// Set month here
[comps setMonth:2]; // 2 = February

NSRange range = [cal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
                          inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit
                         forDate:[cal dateFromComponents:comps]];

NSLog(@"current day count in this month: %lu", (unsigned long)range.length);
```

Comment: That's not quite right. You should use today's dye as the "forDate" parameter. Otherwise you'll get wrong answers for February on leap years.

Comment: @DuncanC It should refer to current date, anyway yes, changing the forDate: parameter maybe with [NSDate date] could be best approach

Answer (score 0):

I have an open source calendar event project. Maybe you can check it out if you need anything. 
[DPCalendar](https://github.com/ethan-fang/DPCalendar)

I have simplied it to

```
- (NSInterger) numberOfDaysForMonth:(NSDate *)date {
    NSCalendar  *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate: date];
    [components setDay:1];
    //Get the first day of the month
    NSDate *firstDay = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

    [components setDay:0];
    [components setMonth:components.month + 1];
    //Get the last day of the month
    NSDate *lastDay = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

    components = [self.calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:firstDay toDate:lastDay options:0];
    return components.day + 1;
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we only need to handle Feb depend on the year, here's my method implemented:

```
+ (NSUInteger)numberOfDaysForYear:(NSInteger)year
                            month:(NSInteger)month
{
  if (2 == month) {
    NSCalendar * gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents * dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComponents setYear:year];
    [dateComponents setMonth:month];
    [dateComponents setDay:1];
    NSDate * firstDayDate = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
    NSRange days = [gregorianCalendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                           inUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth
                                          forDate:firstDayDate];
    return days.length;
  } else if (4 == month || 6 == month || 9 == month || 11 == month) {
    return 30;
  } else {
    return 31;
  }
}
```